# Writing to STVector when within another data constructor

Tags: haskell, vector

I am trying to write a dynamic `STVector` that will be expanded within a `ST monad` (for an imperative algorithm) when the vector capacity is exceeded. To do that, I created a new data constructor that wraps a `STVector`, and add an `Int` to keep track of last inserted vector. The problem is I am getting error from typechecker because it seems my state implementation isn't correct. I will appreciate pointers on how to correctly manage state for `DVec s` in the example below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Test where
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MU
import Control.Monad.ST as ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimState)
import GHC.Float.RealFracMethods (int2Float)

type MVI1 s  = MVector (PrimState (ST s)) Int
data DVec s = DV {-# UNPACK #-}!Int -- this one keeps track of index of last vector
                                (MVI1 s)
append :: DVec s -> Int -> ST s (DVec s)
append (DV i v) x = do
   if i < MU.length v then MU.unsafeWrite v i x >> return $ DV (i+1) v
   else MU.unsafeGrow v (floor $ 1.5 * (int2Float $ MU.length v)) >>= (\y -> MU.unsafeWrite y i x >> return $ DV (i+1) y)
```

Error from typechecker:

```
Couldn't match type `s' with `PrimState ((->) (DVec s))'
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for append :: DVec s -> Int -> ST s (DVec s)
      at B.hs:11:11
Expected type: MVector (PrimState ((->) (DVec s))) Int
  Actual type: MVI1 s
In the first argument of `unsafeWrite', namely `y'
In the first argument of `(>>)', namely `unsafeWrite y i x'
In the expression: unsafeWrite y i x >> return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `$` operator has the least precedence and, thus, everything to the left of it is treated as one function.
Instead of `return $ DV (i+1) v` use `return (DV (i+1) v)`.

**How did I figure this out?**

I removed your type annotation to see what type will ghci determine. Ghci detected a type with this constraint `(Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad ((->) (DVec (PrimState m)))`. This means that there is something wrong which makes ghci think that the `PrimMonad` in use is also a function. It then became obvious that `($)` is the reason behind this.